Ebay Sandbox Offer publish Issue (ShippingCostPaidByOption, ReturnsAcceptedOption, ReturnsWithinOption)
Recently, I've encountered an issue when trying to publish products on my platform. Previously, everything worked smoothly, but now I'm encountering an error preventing the publication of products.
Can anyone help me troubleshoot this problem?
(ShippingCostPaidByOption, ReturnsAcceptedOption, ReturnsWithinOption)
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "errorId": 25009,
      "domain": "API_INVENTORY",
      "subdomain": "Selling",
      "category": "REQUEST",
      "message": "The eBay listing associated with the inventory item, or the unpublished offer has invalid data in the associated Return policy. A return option is missing or not valid. Update your return options.",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "0",
          "value": "ReturnsAcceptedOption"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "errorId": 25009,
      "domain": "API_INVENTORY",
      "subdomain": "Selling",
      "category": "REQUEST",
      "message": "The eBay listing associated with the inventory item, or the unpublished offer has invalid data in the associated Return policy. A return option is missing or not valid. Update your return options.",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "0",
          "value": "ReturnsWithinOption"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "errorId": 25009,
      "domain": "API_INVENTORY",
      "subdomain": "Selling",
      "category": "REQUEST",
      "message": "The eBay listing associated with the inventory item, or the unpublished offer has invalid data in the associated Return policy. A return option is missing or not valid. Update your return options.",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "0",
          "value": "ShippingCostPaidByOption"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "errorId": 25007,
      "domain": "API_INVENTORY",
      "subdomain": "Selling",
      "category": "REQUEST",
      "message": "The eBay listing associated with the inventory item, or the unpublished offer has invalid data in the associated Fulfillment policy. At least one valid shipping service must be specified."
    }
  ]
}


I also was encountering this. I noticed that there was some inconsistent behaviour in the results where even publish offer would return 500 sometimes.
I just pause for 3 seconds in between each call. post the listing, wait three seconds, create the offer, wait three seconds, publish the listing.
That worked. I don't know the minimum time you need to wait in between calls and I haven't experimented yet but it's the only thing that fixed it for me after trying many different things.
